# Lazy load images in table sorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading, tablesorter

From server I get html with table.

To render this table nicely I use table-sorter jquery plugin.

I faced the following issue:

When table enough long page loads really slow. Investigation result - issues related with images downloading. For example I have 100 table rows in my table. I have pagination by 5 lines.
Each line have image and initially when page loads in browser network I see that all 100 images loads.

I want to achieve that image loads only when it is really needs.

I have not expirience in resolving this task.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: You are using fake pagination that is show/hide elements. But your images exists in the DOM hence they are loading. What you need to do is maintain only required elements in the DOM and update DOM as required.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre It is not so comfortable. I loose  table sorter features. Maybe is it possible don't render hided images

Comment: In that case another option will be to use `data-src` as an attribute and load the image when content is visible, makes sense ?

Comment: @Rayon Dabre it looks good but I am not sure that I can realize it. Can you show example?

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle so that I will try on that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your question, I decided to add a lazyload widget to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)... it is currently only in the master branch of the GitHub repository:

- [widget-lazyload.js](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-lazyload.js)
- [example-widget-lazyload.html](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/docs/example-widget-lazyload.html)

If you download or install the repository, run that demo to find documentation on how to setup and use the widget.

I plan on making a new release soon, in case you want to wait.

Comment: it is just fantastic)

Comment: I will wait your release

Comment: You could have used lazysizes: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/. Which automatically works with any other JS component (sliders, tablesorters). Just add the class `lazyload` and use `data-src` instead of `src`.

Comment: Hey @alexanderfarkas! That is a really sweet plugin... I have a feeling I might not even need to have a widget to get that one working :D

Comment: @Mottie, thanks. You won't need to otherwise its considered a bug ;-).

Comment: Link to demo: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-lazyload.html

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to get only necessary html (first page of the table) from server side and update the DOM as required.. maybe ask the server side again.

Then you'd better lazy load those images by using sth like [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Could be as simple as this one:

```
function init() {
    var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}
if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    init();
} else {
    window.onload = init;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oggb1emv/)

Comment: Since you don't want to lose the table sorter feature, you could just have a try with the Lazy Load plugin.

Comment: as I understood this plugin detect visibility by window borders.

Comment: I think if the image is in the viewport it just behave like **data-src** mentioned by @Rayon Dabre

Comment: why do You think that it is lazy loading?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evgdv2m5/) I added timeout to make it more obvious. @gstackoverflow

Comment: It loads image after timeout rather than imges becomes visible

Comment: The point is the image loading is ONLY triggered after the **load** event.@gstackoverflow